# Azure web application and web api service (mobile service) architecture Global distribution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, azure, architecture, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to find resources/info about designing global solution on azure.
Here are demands from my side:

- System needs to have one master database, ofc backup mechanism is needed.
- System need to have web application for various roles etc.
- System need to have some kind of services towards mobile clients. (In
  same MVC app or maybe mobile service?)

Here comes problem:

- System will be distributed global. I think that's fine if mobile
  clients / web clients (from all world) are accessing one server (in azure data cluster
  e.g. North Europe where solution is hosted). Your thinking? There will be intensive 
  communication between mobile clients and services on server (10000
  mobile clients with average 100 requests per minute some of them are
  large (~100KB) JSON objects etc.). Should that mess with performance of clients?
- More important is that mobile clients will do some nw benchmarking
  activities in their region. So they will do DL, UL and latency tests.
  So there is need for some kind of distributed components/services for
  tests.

I'm very new to azure and I'm interested how to design that kind of system with lowest amount of work e.g. what azure offering in that field. I read little about Azure CDN, but that's only for static resources and files.

So, guys, maybe some links, advice ...

BR,
JDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build multiple copies of your application in various Regions and then utilise Traffic Manager (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/) to do least-latency routing for your consumers.  If you need to have data in sync between regions you will need to design your application based on the concept of eventual consistency (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). HTH.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Will do some research on Traffic Management and Eventual Consistency.